# A Jacobian criterion for the tangent space and the tangent cone to be equal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, education

For a lecture that I am preparing as part of an *introductory* course on algebraic varieties, I am trying to give an elementary approach to non-singular points of affine algebraic sets.

I work over an infinite field $k$ of characteristic $0$, not necessarily algebraically closed, and **I would like to show that, if** $Z\subset k^n$ is an algebraic set whose ideal $$\mathcal{I}(Z):= \lbrace P \in k\left[x_1,\ldots ,x_n\right]\ |\ \forall x\in Z, P(x)=0\rbrace$$ is generated by a family of polynomials $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ such that **the Jacobian matrix** $$J_x = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(x) & \ldots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}(x) \\\ \vdots & & \vdots \\\ \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}(x) & \ldots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}(x)  \end{pmatrix},$$ **has rank $m$, *then the tangent cone at $x$ is equal to the Zariski tangent space* at $x$** (of course, this can only happen if $m\leq n$).

The Zariski tangent space $T_xZ$ is (almost by definition) the kernel of $J_x$, meaning that $$T_xZ = \bigcap_{i=1}^m\ker f_i'(x)\ ,$$ while the tangent cone $C_x(Z)$ is defined to be the common zero locus of all initial terms of polynomials in $\mathcal{I}(Z)$: for all $f\in \mathcal{I}(Z)$, denote by $f^\ast_x$ the first non-zero term in the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x$ ($f^\ast_x$ is therefore a symmetric $r$-linear form on $k^n$) and define $$C_x(Z) = \lbrace h\in k^n\ |\ f^\ast_x(h,\ldots,h)=0\rbrace.$$

Since $f'_i(x)$ is the initial term of $f_i$ for all $i\in\lbrace 1,\ldots,m\rbrace$, we always have $C_x(Z)\subset T_xZ$. So the goal is to use the regularity assumption on the Jacobian matrix to prove the converse inclusion.

There is a proof of this in Corollary 10.14-(b) of Andreas Gathmann's 2021 lecture notes (p.82) but it uses the notion of dimension of an algebraic variety, which I do not yet have in the course:

[https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021.pdf)

Note that, for all $f\in\mathcal{I}(Z)$, we can write $f=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i f_i$ for some polynomials $a_i\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Since the linear forms $(f_1'(x),\ldots,f_m'(x))$ are linearly independent, the linear term of $f$ at $x$ is $0$ if and only if $a_i(x)=0$ for all $i \in\lbrace 1,\ldots,m \rbrace$. Can we use this to say something about the initial term of $f$ at $x$? Is this initial term necessarily $0$ on $(h,\ldots,h)$ if $h\in\ker J_x$?

*Notes*

1. Maybe using the Taylor expansion in place of changing the coordinates in order to be able to assume that $x=0$ makes things more complicated: if we do change coordinates and assume that $x=0$, then we can just think of the Taylor expansion as the decomposition of $f$ into homogeneous components and the initial term is just the non-zero homogeneous component of lowest degree. Is it easier to say something about the initial term of $\sum_{i=1}^m a_if_i$ if we think of it this way? An argument along these lines would also have the advantage of being valid in positive characteristic, I believe.
2. In case I am missing something by not supposing $k$ algebraically closed, this assumption can be added (it is not quite what I would like at this basic stage of the course, but it is OK).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: currently incomplete**

Taylor expansion plus coordinate change is in fact the easiest way to prove what you're after.

Change coordinates so that $x=(0,\cdots,0)$. Now the Taylor expansions of the $f_i$ are just the decomposition of the $f_i$ in to homogeneous parts. The fact that the origin is a zero of all the $f_i$ imply that none of them have constant terms, and then the fact that the Jacobian matrix has rank $m$ implies that the linear terms of these $m$ polynomials form a linearly independent set in the vector space of $k\langle x_1,\cdots,x_n\rangle$: writing $f_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j + (\text{higher order terms})$, we see that the vector $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_1}(x) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_n}(x)\end{pmatrix}$$ is exactly $\begin{pmatrix} a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{in}\end{pmatrix}$. So the fact that the Jacobian matrix is of full rank implies the matrix of linear terms of the $f_i$ is of full rank, and therefore they are the leading terms of the $f_i$ and the ideal they generate (which cuts out the tangent cone) has exactly the same zero set as the tangent space. **EDIT:** as pointed out in the comments, this last claim that the initial ideal of $(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ is generated by the linear terms of the $f_i$ needs justification.

Comment: Okay, great, thanks! I think I understand what you wrote, except for the last part: the ideal generated by the leading terms of the $f_i$ ($=$ the linear terms of the $f_i$) is the ideal that cuts out the tangent cone. In general, taking the leading terms of a set of generators of an ideal will not give the ideal that cuts out the tangent cone (e.g. if $f_1=xy$ and $f_2=xz+z(y^2-z^2)$, then $f:= yf_2-zf_1=yz(y^2-z^2)$ is homogeneous of degree $4$ (so the leading term is $f^*=f$) but $f^*$ does not lie in the ideal generated by $f_1^*=xy$ and $f_2^*=xz$). So why exactly does it work here? :-/

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I didn't explain that very well. Thinking about it again, it seems that the way I learned this (Rees algebra, flat specialization, etc) might not be appropriate for an introductory course where you don't even have dimension yet. Would you accept a proof with some power-series tinkering? There's probably a way to do this just from some careful tracking of terms of various degrees, but it will likely be a little messy.

Comment: I would definitely be interested in an argument using power series, yes. It could also be that I was too optimistic thinking that I would be able to present a Jacobian criterion at this stage of the course. It is a bit frustrating not to be able to go beyond the case of a single equation but it is perhaps inevitable without more sophisticated tools (in a differentiable setting, one would probably use the assumption on the rank of the Jacobian to apply the inverse function theorem, and deduce from that that the tangent cone and the tangent space coincide in this case).

Comment: Sorry, the proof I thought I had with power series doesn't quite work - it seems like a good elementary argument should exist here, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding it. Once you know that the dimension of the tangent cone is the dimension of the variety at that point, everything will work, but I am unfortunately unable to furnish the correct argument right now.